# Find and replace a text in all the model in sparx enterprise architect

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I want to replace texts in all the model text, for example, scenario texts and model names and,...
I couldn't find the find and replace feature in sparx ea.
Is it possible to do it with SQL scripts?

I have tried exporting the model in XML format and replacing the text.
I am looking for a better and faster method.

Comment: Yes, no support for that, but scripting is possible. You have to try that. If you got stuck, come back...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a find-replace in all text occurences within the EA model then exporting to XMI, **making changes in the text editor** and importing back is the fastest way.

If you have **specific places to change**, e.g. diagram and element names, notes, etc. then **SQL is an efficient way**.

Anyway, **be careful with SQL updates to your model** as they are pretty risky. I suggest first to check the occurences to which the update applies and only then execute the update itself.

The **safest way is to use EA API** and specify controls what you want to change and what not.